# Issue in v2.0.2-rc1 The CMAKE_ASM-LLVMWAR_COMPILER: g++ is not a full path and was not found in the PATH

Tags: eosio-code, build

CMake Error at libraries/chain/CMakeLists.txt:38 (enable_language):
The CMAKE_ASM-LLVMWAR_COMPILER:

```
g++
```

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
variable "ASM-LLVMWAR" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_ASM-LLVMWAR_COMPILER
to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the
PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean nodeos 2.2.0-rc1 (not 2.0.2-rc1?)

Is the C++ compiler installed? (apt install g++ on ubuntu)